# How does attr_accessible work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just had a general question about Ruby on Rails and the attr_accessible attributes that go in the models (Rails 3).  Can someone explain which model attributes are supposed to be defined there?  I remember something about risk for mass assignment, though I'm not too knowledgeable in this aspect... Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

attr_accessible allows you to define a whitelist of attributes on the model that can be mass assigned. So if you have 10 attrs but only whitelist 3 of them, only those three can be mass assigned.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord:Base
  #lets say you have attrs one, two, three
  attr_accessible :one, :two
end

#You can do this:
Foo.new({:one => 1, :two => 2})

#if you were to do this:
Foo.new({:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3})
#Foo's three attr would not be set
```

Comment: Mhm, will the attributes in attr_accessible be blocked when running my seeds file (my seed file creates an admin user with a higher rank, though obviously the rank will not be available as an open option)?

Comment: Just set it manually in the seeds and not in the init with hash. So: u = User.new(some_hash); u.rank = 1.bajillion; u.save

Answer (score 5):

Imagine an order class with some fields:

```
Order.new({ :type => 'Corn', :quantity => 6 })
```

Now imagine that the order also has a discount code, say :price_off. You wouldn't want to tag :price_off as attr_accessible. This stops malicious code from being able to craft a post that ends up doing something like so:

```
Order.new({ :type => 'Corn', :quantity => 6, :price_off => 30 })
```

Even if your form doesn't have a field for :price_off, if it's just in your model by default it's available. A crafted POST could still set it.

Using attr_accessible white lists those things are can be mass assigned and protects fields that you want explicit control of in your code.

[Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible/3136485#3136485) has some additional links.

Comment: Is it okay to put password and password_confirmation into attr_accessible?  BC when I take them out, It will not allow me to send the password through a sign up page.  I thought that you would not want to have passwords just openly accessible like that?

Comment: It seems to me that a password and a confirmation is something you'd want a user to be able to send, but to the sign-up object not the final user class that results from a sign-up.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.22/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) has some good detail on the topic.

Basically attr_accessible:

> Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via
>   mass-assignment.

And attr_protected:

> Mass-assignment to these attributes will simply be ignored, to assign
>   to them you can use direct writer methods. This is meant to protect
>   sensitive attributes from being overwritten by malicious users
>   tampering with URLs or forms.

Think of attr_accessible as a list of the attributes you want a user to be able to set through a form, anything not on this list wont be able to be set through the mass assignment which ensures that you keep the sensitive values in your database protected from a malicious user. This is a small step to keeping your application secure and you should take a look at the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) if you want to follow Rails best practices.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accessible` is the rails feature with the help of which we can permit mass-assignment for model attributes. It is just opposite to `attr_protected` in functionality. 
To make a particular attribute available for mass-assignment we use `attr_accessible` as follows :

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible : name
end
```

For more detailed explanation about `attr_accessible` and `Strong parameters` you can visit the link given below:

[http://findnerd.com/list/view/attr-accessible-in-Rails-4/3654/][1]