# Rails Accessible Attribute Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mass-assignment

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails and I feel like I am doing something wrong here. I'm setting up a payment model and can't figure out how to do the accessible attributes stuff.

My cash_transaction model has:

```
attr_accessible :billing_address_line_one, :billing_address_line_2, :billing_city, :billing_country, :billing_post_code, :payee_first_name, :payee_last_name, :card_expiry, :card_type

attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification
```

Ok, so I want to submit the form and validate and maybe save to a database in future if the payment goes through.

If I leave `:card_number, :card_verification` in the `attr_accessible`, Rails gives the error:

*unknown attribute card_number*

Which is fair enough because I don't want to save that in my DB.

When I try:

```
@cash_transaction = current_user.cash_transactions.build(params[:cash_transaction])
```

I get a mass assignment security error when those parameters are not in `attr_accessible`.

I have got around both errors with:

```
@cash_transaction = current_user.cash_transactions.build(params[:cash_transaction].except(:card_number, :card_verification))
    @cash_transaction.card_number = params[:cash_transaction][:card_number]
    @cash_transaction.card_verification = params[:cash_transaction][:card_verification]
```

But that's just the same as building with those parameters included in the hash anyway so I'm cheating it?

What do?

Comment: What you are doing looks completely fine.

Comment: However, it looks like you should be able to mass-assign a virtual attribute. So, as long ast you have `attr_accessor :card_number`, you should be able to add it to `attr_accessible` and set it from `params[:cash_transaction]`.

Comment: ah ok, so in both? It appears to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is quite careful against several kinds of [injections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection). And this can be confusing.

`attr_accessible` is a Rails thing, similar to the Ruby Module method `attr_accessor`, yet different. `attr_accessible` does allow access to the specified arguments, much in the same way as `attr_accessor` (the object gets "getters" and "setters"). `attr_accessible` does also more work to protect against injections.

When a parameter dictionary is passed to create an object, each parameter is checked against the [*whitelist*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180459/how-does-attr-accessible-work-in-rails) defined by `attr_accessible`. If the parameter belongs to the list, it gets assigned and persisted. If not, the mass-assignment security error is raised to prevent any unwanted assignment---a potential security hole. `attr_accessor` does not do all that, as it does not make sense in plain Ruby.

Now `card_number` and `card_verification` should not be persisted according to your specifications. They belong to the logic related to cash transaction only, so choosing instance attributes seems a good choice at this point. As plain attributes of CashTransaction instances, they need be treated as such, with plain Ruby access methods. The short answer to all that is @gylaz'.

Wordy feedbacks above. For concrete examples, the ActiveModel's code and related comments are very [informative](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible).