# Is @property and @synthesize in Objective-C the same as attr_accessible in the Ruby Programming Language?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, getter-setter

I can use `@property` and `@synthesize` in Objective-C  so i do not have to write getter and setter methods. In Ruby there is the `attr_accessible` doing the same in my opinion. Am i right or is there a little difference?

Comment: Interesting read on the subject: [Objective C Primer: Part 3 – @property and @synthesize](http://www.optictheory.com/iphone-dev/2010/02/objective-c-primer-part-3-property-and-synthesize/)

Comment: In Ruby, it is not `attr_accessible`, it is `attr_accessor`. `attr_aceessible` is used in Rails framework in a different context. `attr_accessor` defines getter and setter methods for u.

Comment: Oh, my fault good to know. I started with Rails programming and learned Ruby kind of like "top down". But where is the difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessor ?

Comment: see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible) and [this ruby forum question](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/95220)

Answer (score 2):

in basic terms YES

the @synthesize is the one saves you writing the methods

You can also use @dynamic and then implement them yourself.

Comment: Thank you bigkm for answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost right (tm). Probably only deviation is that declaring `@property` with `readonly` modifier would result in `attr_reader` in ruby. And while ruby has `attr_writer` there is no such thing as `writeonly` property in Objective-C.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it's good for you (tick the  box under the vote count).

Answer (score 1):

Basicly yeah, it the same thing :
In ruby you've got the arr_accessible method, who create for you getter and setters.
in objective-c, @property creates directly getter and setter in your .m file.
 example :

```
@interface MaClasse : NSObject {
  int myVariable;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) int myVariable;
@end
```

adding the @property is the same think as creating:

```
-(int)myVariable {
  return myVariable;
}
```

and

```
-(void)setMyVariable:(int)newValue {
  myVariable = newValue;
}
```

you add this methods by adding @synthetize myVariable in your .m file.

in ruby, you just have basicly to do this

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :my_variable 
end
```

`attr_accessor :my_variable` is equivalent to this:

```
def my_variable
  @my_variable
end

def my_variable=(my_variable)
  @my_variable = my_variable
end
```

Comment: I doubt ruby code is correct since `attr_accessor` is declared outside of class's scope.

Comment: Also `myVariable = 0` line is incorrect since `attr_accessor` is defined for instance variables and former variable is declared in class context.

Comment: Simple `@myVariable = 0` would suffice. No need for block .) `def initialize; @myVariable = 0; end;`

Comment: is there a need to initialize the `@myVariable` unless we want a default value...the equivalent ruby code will be one with no `initialize` function..isnt it?

Comment: Yeah, I add the initialize fonction compared to objective c, code, I will delete it to have basicly the same thing in objective c and ruby.

Comment: @victor..u dont need `@myVariable` at all in the code(u dont have to declare variables in Ruby). I edited your answer with this and some more details in the ruby section(and also edited the variable name to follow lower snake case which is the convention)..I hope you dont mind :)