# How do I change value of an attribute that is not attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model.

And User has a field called Balance (which represents how much money he has in his account).

I clearly don't want to make it attr_accessible.

But I want to be able to change its value (say when I charge him for something).

How do I write a getter/setter method for this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@object.attribute = new_value`
`attr_accesible` is a protection from mass assignment don't mess it with `attr_accessor` which creates getters and setters

Here is question about difference [Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accessible` protects you from mass assignment, as used by `update_attributes` and similar.

It doesn't affect reading the value of that attribute at all, and it doesn't affect you calling the accessor directly. For example you could write

```
user.balance -= item.price
user.save!
```

Presuming that you have previously verified that this is indeed the correct action to take.