# Rails 4 + Devise 3.0.0 Adding Username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, strong-parameters

I'm working with Rails 4 and Devise 3.0.0 and am new to using these new strong paramters. I added a username to the User model using the [documentation on the Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address). The problem I'm running into is the strong parameters change in Rails 4.

How do I add the `:login` attribute to the user model to enable logging in with either the username or email?

Comment: Just to expand a bit, I would like to find a solution that I could use that didn't involve reusing the `protected_attributes` gem. If that's possible in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the rails4 readme on devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/rails4#strong-parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :email) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! I guess I should have read the documentation a little bit more carefully. :) I added that and that seemed to help. Now I'm getting `undefined method 'login' for User`. I assume I still need to add something else for the sign in page to recognize the login attribute.

Comment: oh, sorry, you said add a "username" to the model. replace :login with :username above

Comment: The `:login` attribute is just used on the login page to hold the username or email the user types in to login.  I may have to just override the sessions controller to get that to work.

Comment: @justin.chmura let me know if there's anything else to help you with. Otherwise, please mark as accepted.

Comment: @justin.chmura Did you ever get this working? Mind sharing the end solution? How did you end up overriding the sessions controller?

Comment: @AJ. Honestly, I just reverted back to Rails 3 until Rails 4 gets a little bit more fleshed out. Everything I tried didn't work so I gave up for now :)

Answer (score 2):

@justin.chmura

Here is a gist of how we ended up getting it working.
https://gist.github.com/AJ-Acevedo/6077336

Gist contains:
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb
    app/models/user.rb
    config/initializers/devise.rb

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you include the

```
attr_accessor :login
```

in the user model. Here is where I found the question explaining that attr_accessible is deprecated.

[Rails 4 + Devise Login with email or username and strong parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026594/rails-4-devise-login-with-email-or-username-and-strong-parameters)

[Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

This is what my **app/models/user.rb** file looks like.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", { :value => login }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  validates :username,
  :uniqueness => {
    :case_sensitive => false
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It will works fine if you add an module in `config/initializers` as followings with all parameters,

File `config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb` with following contents:

```
module DevisePermittedParameters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```