# Rails 4.0 + Devise 3.0.0 custom attributes to User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working with Rails 4 and Devise 3.0.0 and am new to using these new strong parameters. I added a first_name and last_name to the User model using a migration and then added the following to my application_controller.rb based on the Devise Wiki.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
end
```

My sign_up view (/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb) is blowing up with this error message:

```
undefined method `first_name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fdcbcbe2170>
```

Here's my complete view:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign up</h2>
    <%= f.first_name :first_name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Fist name', :class => "form-control" %>
    <%= f.last_name :last_name, :placeholder => 'List name', :class => "form-control" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email address', :class=> "form-control"  %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder=> 'Password', :class=> "form-control" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder=> 'Password confirmation', :class=> "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'  %>
    <div class="shared_links"><%= render "devise/shared/links" %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

If I remove both :first_name and :last_name lines from the registration#new form everything works fine.

I've look at [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715424/rails-4-devise-3-0-0-adding-username) few [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471498/adding-extra-registration-fields-with-devise) posts with similar issue to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you meant to use `f.text_field :first_name` and `f.text_field :last_name` with your regular options

Comment: @MrYoshiji And you're right...Man, talk about not seeing to big picture and focusing on small issues. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It's okay, end of the day, also a warm day here in Montreal... I understand ;)

Comment: A fellow Montrealer, nice to meet you. And I owe you a beer!

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had accepted it right after you posted it. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use `f.text_field`:

```
# This:
<%= f.first_name :first_name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Fist name', :class => "form-control" %>
<%= f.last_name :last_name, :placeholder => 'List name', :class => "form-control" %>

# Should become:
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Fist name', :class => "form-control" %>
     #^^^^^^^^^^
<%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => 'List name', :class => "form-control" %>
     #^^^^^^^^^^
```