# Append an attribute to a model for temporary use on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model => `@user`

I want to add new attribute `current_time` to `@user` for temporary use.

Don't want to do migration to add a column (just for temporary use):

```
@user.current_time = Time.now
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `current_time=' for #<User:0x007fd6991e1050>):
  app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:47:in `block in search_user'
  app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:45:in `search_user'
```

Answer (score 5):

[`attr_accessor`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) will set up a reader and writer for the instance variable:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :current_time
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.current_time = Time.now   # Writes value
foo.current_time              # Reads value
```

You might also be interested in `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define few methods in User.model:

```
def current_time= (time)
  @current_time = time
end

def current_time
  @current_time
end
```

**UPD** according to precisely right comment from *kristinalim*

Note, that `attr_accessible`, being part of framework, was deprecated in Rails 4. Now strong params are used instead. At the same time getter/setter `attr_accessor` is part of core Ruby and works as usual.

The difference between `attr_accessible` and `attr_accessor` is in very well explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

Comment: Do you mean that `attr_accessible` is deprecated? AFAIK, `attr_accessor` is part of Ruby core and is still alive.