# Capybara throws error when setting an attribute in an instance method, because its undefined, but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm using Capybara for integration testing and I noticed that it throws errors when you attempt to set an attribute from within an instance method, for example:

```
def set_password_reset_token
  self.password_reset_token = self.class.generate_token
end
```

Where password_reset_token is a database column that is attr_accessible. This instance method works fine, but when it is tested using Capybara, for example:

```
it "updates the user password when confirmation matches" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user.set_password_reset_token
  visit edit_password_reset_url(user.password_reset_token)       
  fill_in "password", with: "123456"
  click_button "Update Password"
  expect(page).to have_content("Password has been reset")
end
```

The following failure occurs:

```
PasswordResets
  updates the user password when confirmation matches (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) PasswordResets updates the user password when confirmation matches
     Failure/Error: user.set_password_reset_token
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password_reset_token=' for #<User:0x007fd237d31e20>
     # ./app/models/user.rb:107:in `set_password_reset_token'
     # ./spec/features/password_resets_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19426 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/password_resets_spec.rb:23 # PasswordResets updates the user password when confirmation matches
```

This is true, there is no password_reset_token= method. User.instance_methods.include?(:password_reset_token=) returns false. However, the attribute is set correctly when the code is actually executed. I'm curious why the error occurs and what can be done to make the tests pass. Does Capybara test for the method by calling instance_methods.include?, why doesn't it just execute the code and see if an error is raised?

Comment: I tried that and still receive same error

Answer (score 1):

`attr_accessor`, not `attr_accessible`, automatically defines a getter and setter method. You can read more about it in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible).

So in your case, you could add `password_reset_token` to `attr_accessor` or change your `set_reset_password_token` to:

```
def set_password_reset_token
  password = self.class.generate_token
  self.update_attribute(:password_reset_token, password)
end
```

Comment: I understand that, however, your answer is incorrect. I don't need getter and setter methods via attr_accessor to set a database column. Attr_accessible allows me to assign the db column a value. If I use attr_accessor will actually break the execution of the code.

Comment: I also tried changing the set_password_reset_token method as you mentioned and it throws an error, unknown attribute, password_reset_token, depsite the password_reset_token being defined in the schema and as attr_accessible...

Comment: In addition, keep in mind that the code executes correctly, meaning the password_reset_token is set with a value. The only thing that doesn't work is the test passing. That's why my question was in relation to Capybara.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because the test environment hadn't been migrated. Once I migrated the test environment, the tests all passed.