# Password digest missing on new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think a lot of people have asked this question, but unfortunately I didn't understand the answers they were given. Basically, I need you guys to just say, "AND THIS IS THE CODE YOU NEED HERE PASTE," and then explain it to me because, frankly, I don't get it.

Okay, so here's the issue. I'm running a test for my user model, and this is what happens:

```
1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
 Failure/Error: before { @user.save }
 RuntimeError:
   Password digest missing on new record
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
 Failure/Error: before { @user.save }
 RuntimeError:
   Password digest missing on new record
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
 Failure/Error: before { @user.save }
 RuntimeError:
   Password digest missing on new record
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Now for my code. Here's my rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
before do
    @user = User.new(first: "Example", last: "Example", email: "user@andover.edu", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end

subject { @user }

it { should respond_to(:first) }
it { should respond_to(:last) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }  
it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
it { should respond_to(:password) } 
it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

it { should be_valid }

describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.first = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.first = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.last = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.last = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
     addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    addresses.each do |invalid_address|
    @user.email = invalid_address
    expect(@user).not_to be_valid
  end
end
end

describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
    addresses = %w[cwolford@andover.edu]
    addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    expect(@user).to be_valid
  end
end
end

describe "return value of authenticate method" do
  before { @user.save }
  let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

  describe "with valid password" do
    it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
  end

  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
  end
end

end
```

And here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :first, :last, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password

before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
validates :first, :last, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[andover]+\.[edu]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

And here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem "protected_attributes", :github => "rails/protected_attributes"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I'm not going to waste more space by posting my schema, but I do want to say that I put this in the schema: t.string   "password_digest". I know that was a problem for some people, since they left it off.

Your thoughts?

Comment: I would say you need to remove `attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation` from your `User` model.

Comment: THANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKOYOU! That was hours of work finally fixed! I can finally move on to making my join table. *foreverindebted*

Comment: No problem! :) - I'll write a full answer as to _why_ it was that too.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

remove `attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation` from your `User` model.

**Reason:**

First, understand the difference between `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible` - there are many good explanations on SO already eg:

[Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

As ruby interprets the `User` model one line at a time it gets to:

```
attr_accessible :first, :last, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Which is fine.....until the very next line:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
```

When it overrides the `:password` and `:password_confirmation` attributes to make them `attr_accessor`

Which is why the error occurred it your specs when you called `@user.save`

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user2253215 if this answer was correct and solved the issue then please accept, thanks =)