# Rails nested form not saving children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many

My User model has_many Responses. I'm trying to create a nested form to create a new user with three child responses. My code looks identical to the Rails cast, but although it will save the user it does not save their responses. Can anyone see what is wrong?

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    3.times{@user.responses.build}
    @responses = @user.responses
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user #todo: where do we want to redirect?
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @responses = @user.responses
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :responses)
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :responses_attributes
  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses#, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :username,  length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } ,
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false};

  validates :responses, presence: true
end
```

**response.rb**

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :content
end
```

**users/new.html.erb (the form)**

```
<h1>This is a test form for adding Users with child Responses</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <p>
    <%= f.fields_for :responses do |builder| %>
          <%= builder.label :content, "Response" %>
          <%= builder.text_field :content %>
    <% end %>
    </p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

I have change the strong parameters in the Users controller to:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, responses_attributes: [:content])
end
```

And I have updated the User model to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses#, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :username,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } ,
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false};

  validates_associated :responses, presence: true
end
```

Now it continues to fail my validations for the responses, and also fails my validations for username and email.

Comment: @iandotkelly, It is simply failing my validations for response presence; if I take out the validations it saves it properly but without the attached responses.

Comment: Rails is definitely a bad parent if it's not saving children

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your Response class:

```
validates_presence_of :user_id, :content
```

This validation requires the existence of `user_id`, which means the User has to be created before Response. To make it work you can try couple of things:

- Change `validates_presence_of :user_id` to `validates_presence_of :user` to make it validate the `User` object instead of the user's id.
- Use `inverse_of` option. See the [Rails API doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).

Updated code.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :responses_attributes
  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses

  # ...
end
```

**response.rb**

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :responses
  validates_presence_of :user, :content
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for RoR v3:**

The problem is the following line in your `User` model:

```
attr_accessor :responses_attributes
```

Replace it with:

```
attr_accessible :responses_attributes
```

The answer to question [`Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible) should help you understand the difference between the two.

Also your validation `validates :responses, presence: true` needs to be updated to use `validates_associated`:

```
validates_associated :responses, presence: true
```

**Answer for RoR v4:**

I hadn't noticed the use of Strong parameters ealier, apologies for this.  A couple of changes should fix your issue:

1. Remove `attr_accessor :responses_attributes` from `User` model.
2. Replace `validates :responses, presence: true` with `validates_associated :responses, presence: true`
3. Define `responses` attributes in permit list.

Something like follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessor :responses_attributes # Remove this line
  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses#, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  ...

  validates_associated :responses, presence: true # Update here
end

#Users Controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :responses_attributes[:content])
    end
end
```

Comment: I replaced this line with "attr_accessible :responses_attributes, :responses, :email, :username". I had to add 'protected_attributes' to the Gemfile to get Rails to accept attr_accessible. The responses are still not being saved.

Comment: @user3234309, please see the updates.  I didn't notice the use of strong parameters earlier.  With the Rails4 way above, you can remove the `protected_attributes` gem.

Comment: after removing the attr_accessible line and the gem now it is failing my validations for the username and email as well. I have added "responses_attributes: [:content]" to the strong parameters. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost correct:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responses

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :username,  length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } ,
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false};
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
private

def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, responses_attributes: [:content])
end
```