# How to save datetime fields with validations? [Ruby / Rails 4 / Postgres]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

Ok, so I need help with datetime database fields.

Let's say my table is called "events" and has a datetime field named "starts_at".  I have confirmed this in my schema.rb file (technically I am using Postgres):

```
create_table "events", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name",                        null: false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.datetime "starts_at
  ...
end
```

In my event.rb model, I have a validation to make sure the starts_at datetime is set:

```
attr_accessor :starts_at
validates :starts_at, presence: true
```

I'm testing this via the **rails console** and I can't get it to save any value, let alone create any validation errors.  What gives?  For example:

```
e = Event.new
e.name = 'Post 1'
e.starts_at = DateTime.now.utc
e.save
```

It appears to save, but there is no validation error, no mention of "starts_at" in the displayed query.  Starts_at is nil in the database.  My schema defines it as a "datetime" field but it ignores my DateTime variable.  I thought, ok, maybe it is technically a string field and rails doesn't auto-convert for me:

```
e = Event.new
e.name = 'Post 2'
e.starts_at = DateTime.now.utc.to_s
e.save
```

Same thing.  Thinking that the resulting format is being rejected in Postgres, I try this:

```
e = Event.new
e.name = 'Post 3'
e.starts_at = DateTime.now.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
e.save
```

I thought it might work with:

```
e.starts_at = Time.now.utc
```

Or, for Unix timestamp integer style:

```
e.starts_at = DateTime.now.utc.to_i
```

Nope, nothing works.  What am I doing wrong?

Some questions:

1. How do I get a datetime field to accept my input -- any input! -- and actually save it to the database?  Do I need to know which time format is ultimately being used by the database type (Postgres, MySQL, etc) and adjust accordingly?  i.e. How does database agnosticism apply?
2. How can I update my validation to check if the database actually accepted my input?  It's counterintuitive that I am validating the presence of my starts_at variable, but it will in fact allow it to be saved as nil.

Comment: are you using attr_accessor for :starts_at? or protected_attributes?

Comment: Yes my model has "attr_accessor :starts_at".  Post edited to reflect that.

Comment: remove that and try again.

Comment: Ok, it's saving now... but... why?  I guess I will do some reading up on the details.

Comment: will update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
attr_accessor :starts_at
```

It masks the original setter that comes with Rails and sets a instance variable instead.

If there is a column (like the `starts_at` column here) in the database then there is no need to define a getter oder setter method on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Probable issue is that Rails is protecting you from mass assignment of variables.

You need to remove attr_accessor on that columns that are saved as NULL in the database.

Explained really well here - [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) and [Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

Comment: But I'm not using mass assignment.  The code blocks above were typed manually via the rails console, I wasn't passing a hash into create() or new() as I would think would matter in the context of mass assignment.  I am specifically updating just the starts_at field... thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible