# Difference from attr_accessor and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation and
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
```

Who can tell me whats the difference

Comment: check this-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessor is ruby method. It sets getter and setter. However, attr_accessible is a rails method that will allow to pass values in mass assignment.

For example-

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
u = User.new({ :password => 'XXX', :password_confirmation => 'XXX' })
---
u.password => nil
u.password_confirmation => nil
```

But, you will be able to user getter and setter values in this case.

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
u.password = 'XXX'
---
u.password => 'XXX'
```

On the other hand for attr_accessible -

```
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
User.new({ :password => 'XXX', :password_confirmation => 'XXX' })
---
u.password => 'XXX'
u.password_confirmation => 'XXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr-accessor` creates the `getter` and `setter` methods for the specified attributes

`method.attribute` (getter)

`method.attribute` = (setter)

`attr_accessible` is from `ActiveRecord::Base` and "Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment."