# Rails 4 strong params - Undefined method name on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, strong-parameters

I recently converted to Rails 4 and strong params, and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

My model looks like so:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  validates :name, :email, :body, :presence => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

It's my understanding that I don't need a controller containing strong params for this model, because I'm strictly "getting" it. I'm not updating or saving it anywhere, so I don't need to permit any params to be passed through. However, to be sure, I have this controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  private

  def message_params
      params.require(:message_params).permit(:name, :email, :body)
  end
end
```

This throws an error:

```
message = Message.new
message.name = 'test'

NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for #<Message:0x007f9d620706f0>
```

My model used to contain this:

```
attr_accessor :name, :email, :body
```

And it worked fine. What am I missing in my rails 4 upgrade, and what do I need to change to gain access to these attributes again?

Comment: I suppose you are creating a tableless model so you need to include attr_accessor that will create setter and getter methods for the attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still do need the `attr_accessor` defining which attributes your model has.

There's also a `ActiveModel::Model` module you can include rather than including separate modules:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body

  validates :name, :email, :body, :presence => true

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

See the [ActiveModel documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

So you're still going to want to use attr_accessor.  You're mixing it up with attr_accessible.
Take a look at this answer: [Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

attr_accessor is "is a ruby method that makes a getter and a setter" while attr_accessible is now an unsupported "rails method that allows you to pass in values to a mass assignment: new(attrs) or up update_attributes(attrs)."

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a tableless model. The accessor methods are **not created** for your model by default. You need to add **attr_accessor** for the attributes of this specific model explicitly in order to read and write the attributes. Hence, the error.

For models with table, the model class extends from **ActiveRecord::Base** which takes care of creating the accessor methods for attributes dynamically so you don't specify **attr_accesor** there.