# Difference between attr_accessible and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, attr-accessible

I have just been doing a bit of reading on `attr_accessor`, `attr_accessible` and strong parameters at a few different locations:

[Difference between attr_accessor and attr_accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3136420/3507417)
[How is attr_accessible used in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17371334/3507417) 
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

And I am looking at mass assignment:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695

I can't get my head around the difference between `attr_accessible` and strong parameters. I am not 100% confident in my understanding of the subjects mentioned above so I could be missing something simple but I know they do a similar job.

However, what is the difference between `attr_accessible` and strong parameters? Are they just a different name for the same thing? Why did we move from one to the other?

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

attr_accessible has been deprecated in Rails 4 in favor of Strong Parameters.

Both are different approaches to the mass assignment problem but Strong Parameters is more flexible.

In example, you have an `User`model with the attributes `email:string` and `is_admin:boolean`. You wish to allow the users to modify their email through a form but not the `is_admin` field.

In Rails 3 you should do:

```
attr_accesible :email
```

With this approach it's not possible for an user to modify `is_admin` because that attribute is protected.

One of the good things of Strong Parameters is that you could do the following in your controller:

```
def user_params
  if current_user.admin?
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :is_admin)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

This way one admin user will be able to modify `is_admin` while a normal user won't.

This is just one example and not the best way to grant administrative permissions to an user but it's quite illustrative.

The main advantage of Strong Parameters is that they are defined in the controller and can be dynamically assigned in run time. attr_accessible was a more static and monolithic way to whitelist attributes.

On the other hand attr_accessor is completely different thing and still can be used in Rails 4, in example, if you need one attribute in your model that it's not necessary to persist or to be written into the database but you require it in a form. Think about:

`attr_accessor :has_accepted_legal_terms`

It's a Ruby method that can be used to declare an attribute of your model that is not related to the database, an attribute of a Class or PORO (plain old ruby object).

Answer (score 11):

**Strong parameters and `attr_accessible` are two different ways of adding security protections to the Rails "mass assignment" feature**. Strong Parameters is the way that is prescribed by the current version of Rails.

"Mass assignment" is a convenient shorthand in Rails that allows you to set many properties of a model in a single statement.

For example, imagine you have a `@user` that you want to update with data from a form submission. Without mass assignment, you'd have to write tedious code like this:

```
@user.first_name = params[:user][:first_name]
@user.last_name = params[:user][:last_name]
@user.phone_number = params[:user][:phone_number]
...
@user.save
```

And on and on for every form field.

With mass assignment, all of that code becomes a single line:

```
@user.update(params[:user])
```

**But, this is full of security holes.** Since `params` contains whatever data was submitted by the browser, a malicious user could add data to that submission that you did not expect. For example, they could add `is_admin=1` to the parameters. If you have an `is_admin` database column, then mass assignment just let the user upgrade to an administrator. Yikes!

This is where Strong Parameters comes in. With Strong Parameters, Rails will raise a `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` if you try to do the naïve `update(params[:user])`. Instead, you need to be explicit about what parameters you expect from the browser submission, using the `require` and `permit` helpers that Strong Parameters provides. Like this:

```
def user_params
  # Note that :is_admin is not permitted!
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number)
end

...
@user.update(user_params)
```

I can't speak for the maintainers of Rails, but I like Strong Parameters because it is flexible. If I have multiple actions in the users controller that expect different parameters, I can easily describe using `permit` the parameters that should be allowed.

Or if I have different user roles that are allowed to update different attributes, then I can easily model those permissions. As @CV-Gate mentioned, you can even change these permissions at runtime, which is a powerful.

In short, the flexibility of Strong Parameters is due to the fact that you can define that `user_params` method anywhere, and however you like. You have the full power of Ruby and OO concepts to make it work the way you want.

**What about `attr_accessible`?**

Without going into too much detail (since this feature is no longer supported by Rails): instead of using the `permit` method, you would do something similar using an `attr_accessible` macro in the model itself, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number
  ...
end
```

So for simple cases, it works very similar to Strong Parameters; you just define the list of attributes in a different place.

However, since `attr_accessible` is strongly coupled with the definition of the model class, you lose a lot of flexibility. What if you have two different controller actions that need to do mass assignment for the same `User` model? Now you are stuck.

**`attr_accessor`**

The `attr_accessor` macro is built into Ruby and has nothing to do with Rails, mass assignment, or security. It just happens to have a similar name. :)