# Rails activerecord-reputation-system form_for does not accept params that don't exist in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I am trying to use this gem activerecord-reputation-system https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system

However that is not the problem I am running into, I am running into a problem with how ActiveRecord works with accepting params using form_for

Currently I have the :teacher param being saved in the update method of the controller like this:

```
@course.add_evaluation(key,  params[:teacher],   current_user)
```

In my view, this is the form I am using to submit to the Course

```
= form_for @course do |f|
  = f.number_field :teacher
  = f.submit
```

When you submit the form it gives this error

```
undefined method `teacher' for #<Course:0x007f00ea2f4030>
```

I know it gives this error because the "teacher" column does not exist in the Course, however I don't want it to exist in the Course because it already exists in the reputation tables.

Am I going about this the wrong way? How to I ensure that the reputation gets added to a specific course if I can't use this?

```
form_for @course
```

Do I have to do something like this? This feels like poor programming to me.

```
form_tag courses_path + course_name, :method => 'post'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a virtual attribute to your Course model like

```
attr_accessor :teacher
```

You may want to check this answer first

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136485/522897

Comment: This worked flawlessly, I forget about attr_accessor, thanks for the reminder