# Issue with inserting data into database via rails command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue with inserting data via rails command. Bellow you can see my model and the issue. The title is displaying nil even tho I created a new instance of Post with the title hash. I am aware you can do this in a different way. I am using this simple example to figure out why can't I insert or display data from the database.

## Model

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :name
  has_many :posts
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :title, :body, :category_id, :author_id
  belongs_to :category
end
```

## Rails c

```
post = Post.new(:title => 'Test')
=> #<Post id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, category_id: nil, author_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Comment: See the difference of `attr_accessor` (ruby level) vs `attr_accessible` (rails level) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible

Comment: I get this error when i use attr_accessible 
Undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x0000000cd719f8> Did you mean? attr_accessor

Comment: See first answer's comments as they explain why it is not working for Rails 4+

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the `attr_accessor` in your Rails class. Rails automatically make these attributes readable, and you should generally only be writing by saving records to the database.