# uploading a file to Rails JSON API server with Paperclip and Multipart request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to upload a file from an Android client to a Rails JSON API server.

I'm sending a Multipart/form request from the Android client which looks like that:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d99ArGa2SaAsrXaGL_AdkNlmGn2wuflo5
Host: 10.0.2.2:3000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

--d99ArGa2SaAsrXaGL_AdkNlmGn2wuflo5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="POSTDATA"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{"tags":["test"],"location_id":1,"post":{"content":"test"}}
--d99ArGa2SaAsrXaGL_AdkNlmGn2wuflo5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="IMAGEDATA"; filename="testimage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<BINARY DATA?
--d99ArGa2SaAsrXaGL_AdkNlmGn2wuflo5--
```

in the rails controller i'm creating the new post with this code:

```
@parsed_json = JSON(params[:POSTDATA])
@post = @current_user.posts.new(@parsed_json["post"])
```

how do I make Paperclip save the attachment from the multipart form ?

I can do it with something like this:

```
if params.has_key?(:IMAGEDATA)
    photo = params[:IMAGEDATA]
    photo.rewind

    @filename = "/tmp/tempfile"
    File.open(@filename, "wb") do |file|
      file.write(photo.read)
    end

    @post.photo = File.open(@filename)
  end
```

but it doesn't look like the best solution, also, the filename that is being passed in ther multipart request is not used.

Answer (score 12):

The pure json way to do this is to not pass content-type multipart-form and pass the file as a base64 encoded string in the json.

I figured this out thanks this post: http://www.rqna.net/qna/xyxun-paperclip-throws-nohandlererror-with-base64-photo.html

Here's an example of the json:

```
"{\"account\":{\"first_name\":\"John\",\"last_name\":\"Smith\",\"email\":\"john@test.com\",\"password\":\"testtest\",\"avatar\":{\"data\":\"INSERT BASE64 ENCODED STRING OF FILE HERE\",\"filename\":\"avatar.jpg\",\"content_type\":\"image/jpg\"}}}"
```

Then in the controller process the incoming avatar like this before saving the model.

```
def process_avatar
  if params[:account] && params[:account][:avatar]
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(params[:account][:avatar][:data]))
    data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    data.original_filename = params[:account][:avatar][:filename]
    data.content_type = params[:account][:avatar][:content_type]
    params[:account][:avatar] = data
  end
end
```

Comment: This is working so far. I am fine, but can somebody explain me how this can work, that we actually filling params[:account][:avatar] with  StringIO class?

Comment: This is half working for me, if the picture is too large and so is the base64 string then it crashes and raise the Errno::E2BIG exception.

Comment: I think it's more clean to more this logic to the model as documented here: http://eggie5.com/54-ios-rails-image-uploads

Answer (score 4):

So, I'm guessing your `Post` model looks something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { ... }
  ...
end
```

So you should be able to do something as simple as this:

```
@post.photo = params[:IMAGEDATA] if params[:IMAGEDATA].present?
@post.save if @post.valid?
```

And it should save the photo.

If you need to do something more complicated, try re-arranging the form data into the data that the format Paperclip expects. And if you need to dig deeper, [take a look inside Paperclip's `Paperclip::Attachment` class](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb).

**Stack Overflow Cross-Reference**

- [Save Files Using Paperclip via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228188/save-files-using-paperclip-via-api)
- [Paperclip at Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/)